# Скачать файл excel с сайта selenuim+python

Tags: python, excel, selenium

Всем привет, есть некий сайт, там всякие отчеты в формате excel,  мне надо скачивать этих отчетов с нужными датами, иногда отчеты за 2 дня иногда за целый месяц, отдельными файлами, например отчет за 1 мая, за 2 мая и тд. Уважаемые подскажите как, имею базовые знания selenium+python. спасибо заранее.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

а с какого именно сайта вы хотите скачивать отчеты.

Один из возможных вариантов.
Для того что бы скачать отчеты нужно посмотреть какой идет get запрос с сайта на сервер и проанализировать его, вдруг там попадутся некоторые из настроек которые вы хотите ставить при помощи Selenium.

Еще один вариант.
Можно при помощи селекторов определять элемент и используя Selenium взаимодействовать с ним.